# Scaling down texture

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-coordinates

When building this building, when I add the brick texture, it's way too big (as should be expeted). And I know I should probably already know this but, how do you get it to scale down? I've triesd adding Texture Coordinate>Mapping>Image Texture and everything turns cream colored.[image]

[image: ext]

Answer (score 1):

In your *Mapping* node, it looks like *Texture* increases the size of your image texture, instead of reducing it, so decrease it or use *Point*. Also, if you've unwrapped your object, use *Texture Coordinate* > *UV* output instead of *Generated*.

[image]

Comment: Thank so much! Now they're vertical. When I rotate it along an axis, it messes everything up. How do I fix this?

Comment: it depends what sort of mapping method you've chosen, if you didn't unwrap your object it won't be very controllable, you can try Box instead of Flat in your Image Texture, but if it doesn't give any good result you'll have to mark seam and unwrap your object, please follow some tutorials about that because it's a completely different topic  ;)